# Keycloak PUT Group APIs failing in case of large payload size

Tags: keycloak, keycloak-rest-api

We have been using Keycloak attributes in groups to store some large payload values. But we have noticing when adding a large payload like the below example:

```
{
  "id": "42f508af-03f1-42ee-aafa-721cd06a9962",
  "name": "test-group",
  "path": "/formsflow-analytics/test-group",
  "attributes": {
    "dashboards": [
      "[{'6': 'New Business License Application'}, {'7': 'Freedom Of Information Form'}, {'12': 'dashboard4'}, {'1': 'SAMPLE'}, {'2': 'SAMPL'}, {'5': 'New Business License Application'}, {'9': 'Freedom of Information and Protection of Privacy'},{'1': 'GROUP1'},{'2': 'SAMPLE1'}]"
    ]
  },
  "realmRoles": [],
  "clientRoles": {},
  "subGroups": [],
  "access": {
    "view": true,
    "manage": true,
    "manageMembership": true
  }
}
```

gives a 500 internal server error with response:

```
{"error":"unknown_error"}
```

[image]

Keycloak logs:

```
07:56:06,323 ERROR [io.undertow.request] (default task-14) UT005023: Exception handling request to /auth/admin/realms/forms-flow-ai/groups/2a74cd01-3b09-453b-ac5b-90ffa95e8c2a: org.keycloak.models.ModelException: org.hibernate.exception.DataException: could not execute statement
        at org.keycloak.keycloak-model-jpa@14.0.0//org.keycloak.connections.jpa.PersistenceExceptionConverter.convert(PersistenceExceptionConverter.java:84)
        at org.keycloak.keycloak-model-jpa@14.0.0//org.keycloak.connections.jpa.JpaExceptionConverter.convert(JpaExceptionConverter.java:31)
        at org.keycloak.keycloak-services@14.0.0//org.keycloak.transaction.JtaTransactionWrapper.lambda$handleException$0(JtaTransactionWrapper.java:65)
        at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:195)
        at java.base/java.util.HashMap$ValueSpliterator.forEachRemaining(HashMap.java:1675)
        at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:484)
        at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:474)
        at java.base/java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp.evaluateSequential(ForEachOps.java:150)
        at java.base/java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp$OfRef.evaluateSequential(ForEachOps.java:173)      
        at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234)
        at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.forEach(ReferencePipeline.java:497)
        at org.keycloak.keycloak-services@14.0.0//org.keycloak.transaction.JtaTransactionWrapper.handleException(JtaTransactionWrapper.java:67)
        at org.keycloak.keycloak-services@14.0.0//org.keycloak.transaction.JtaTransactionWrapper.commit(JtaTransactionWrapper.java:92)
        at org.keycloak.keycloak-services@14.0.0//org.keycloak.services.DefaultKeycloakTransactionManager.commit(DefaultKeycloakTransactionManager.java:136)
        at org.keycloak.keycloak-services@14.0.0//org.keycloak.services.filters.AbstractRequestFilter.close(AbstractRequestFilter.java:64)
        at org.keycloak.keycloak-services@14.0.0//org.keycloak.services.filters.AbstractRequestFilter.filter(AbstractRequestFilter.java:49)
        at org.keycloak.keycloak-wildfly-extensions@14.0.0//org.keycloak.provider.wildfly.WildFlyRequestFilter.doFilter(WildFlyRequestFilter.java:39)
        at io.undertow.servlet@2.2.5.Final//io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:61)
        at io.undertow.servlet@2.2.5.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131)
        at io.undertow.servlet@2.2.5.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler.handleRequest(FilterHandler.java:84)
        at io.undertow.servlet@2.2.5.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletSecurityRoleHandler.handleRequest(ServletSecurityRoleHandler.java:62)
        at io.undertow.servlet@2.2.5.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletChain$1.handleRequest(ServletChain.java:68)
        at io.undertow.servlet@2.2.5.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletDispatchingHandler.handleRequest(ServletDispatchingHandler.java:36)
        at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@23.0.2.Final//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.SecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:78)
        at io.undertow.core@2.2.5.Final//io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
        at io.undertow.servlet@2.2.5.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.RedirectDirHandler.handleRequest(RedirectDirHandler.java:68)
        at io.undertow.servlet@2.2.5.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.SSLInformationAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SSLInformationAssociationHandler.java:117)
        at io.undertow.servlet@2.2.5.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.handleRequest(ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.java:57)
        at io.undertow.core@2.2.5.Final//io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
        at io.undertow.core@2.2.5.Final//io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractConfidentialityHandler.handleRequest(AbstractConfidentialityHandler.java:46)
        at io.undertow.servlet@2.2.5.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.handleRequest(ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.java:64)
        at io.undertow.core@2.2.5.Final//io.undertow.security.handlers.AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.handleRequest(AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.java:60)
        at io.undertow.servlet@2.2.5.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.handleRequest(CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.java:77)
        at io.undertow.core@2.2.5.Final//io.undertow.security.handlers.NotificationReceiverHandler.handleRequest(NotificationReceiverHandler.java:50)
        at io.undertow.core@2.2.5.Final//io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractSecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(AbstractSecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:43)
        at io.undertow.core@2.2.5.Final//io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
        at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@23.0.2.Final//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.jacc.JACCContextIdHandler.handleRequest(JACCContextIdHandler.java:61)
        at io.undertow.core@2.2.5.Final//io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
        at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@23.0.2.Final//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.GlobalRequestControllerHandler.handleRequest(GlobalRequestControllerHandler.java:68)
        at io.undertow.servlet@2.2.5.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.SendErrorPageHandler.handleRequest(SendErrorPageHandler.java:52)
        at io.undertow.core@2.2.5.Final//io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
        at io.undertow.servlet@2.2.5.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.handleFirstRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:269)
        at io.undertow.servlet@2.2.5.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$100(ServletInitialHandler.java:78)
        at io.undertow.servlet@2.2.5.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$2.call(ServletInitialHandler.java:133)
        at io.undertow.servlet@2.2.5.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$2.call(ServletInitialHandler.java:130)
        at io.undertow.servlet@2.2.5.Final//io.undertow.servlet.core.ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction$1.call(ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction.java:48)
        at io.undertow.servlet@2.2.5.Final//io.undertow.servlet.core.ContextClassLoaderSetupAction$1.call(ContextClassLoaderSetupAction.java:43)
        at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@23.0.2.Final//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.SecurityContextThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(SecurityContextThreadSetupAction.java:105)
        at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@23.0.2.Final//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1530)
        at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@23.0.2.Final//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1530)
        at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@23.0.2.Final//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1530)
        at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@23.0.2.Final//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1530)
        at io.undertow.servlet@2.2.5.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.dispatchRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:249)
        at io.undertow.servlet@2.2.5.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$000(ServletInitialHandler.java:78)
        at io.undertow.servlet@2.2.5.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$1.handleRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:99)
        at io.undertow.core@2.2.5.Final//io.undertow.server.Connectors.executeRootHandler(Connectors.java:387)        at io.undertow.core@2.2.5.Final//io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange$1.run(HttpServerExchange.java:841)
        at org.jboss.threads@2.4.0.Final//org.jboss.threads.ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.run(ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.java:35)
        at org.jboss.threads@2.4.0.Final//org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor.safeRun(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1990)
        at org.jboss.threads@2.4.0.Final//org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.doRunTask(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1486)
        at org.jboss.threads@2.4.0.Final//org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1377)
        at org.jboss.xnio@3.8.4.Final//org.xnio.XnioWorker$WorkerThreadFactory$1$1.run(XnioWorker.java:1280)  
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.DataException: could not execute statement
        at org.hibernate@5.3.20.Final//org.hibernate.exception.internal.SQLStateConversionDelegate.convert(SQLStateConversionDelegate.java:118)
        at org.hibernate@5.3.20.Final//org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:42)
        at org.hibernate@5.3.20.Final//org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:113)
        at org.hibernate@5.3.20.Final//org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:99)
        at org.hibernate@5.3.20.Final//org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.executeUpdate(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:178)
        at org.hibernate@5.3.20.Final//org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3192)
        at org.hibernate@5.3.20.Final//org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3706)
        at org.hibernate@5.3.20.Final//org.hibernate.action.internal.EntityInsertAction.execute(EntityInsertAction.java:90)
        at org.hibernate@5.3.20.Final//org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:604)
        at org.hibernate@5.3.20.Final//org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:478)
        at org.hibernate@5.3.20.Final//org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractFlushingEventListener.performExecutions(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:356)
        at org.hibernate@5.3.20.Final//org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultFlushEventListener.onFlush(DefaultFlushEventListener.java:39)
        at org.hibernate@5.3.20.Final//org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.doFlush(SessionImpl.java:1472)      
        at org.hibernate@5.3.20.Final//org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.managedFlush(SessionImpl.java:512)
        at org.hibernate@5.3.20.Final//org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.flushBeforeTransactionCompletion(SessionImpl.java:3310)
        at org.hibernate@5.3.20.Final//org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.beforeTransactionCompletion(SessionImpl.java:2506)
        at org.hibernate@5.3.20.Final//org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcCoordinatorImpl.beforeTransactionCompletion(JdbcCoordinatorImpl.java:447)
        at org.hibernate@5.3.20.Final//org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jta.internal.JtaTransactionCoordinatorImpl.beforeCompletion(JtaTransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:352)
        at org.hibernate@5.3.20.Final//org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jta.internal.synchronization.SynchronizationCallbackCoordinatorNonTrackingImpl.beforeCompletion(SynchronizationCallbackCoordinatorNonTrackingImpl.java:47)
        at org.hibernate@5.3.20.Final//org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jta.internal.synchronization.RegisteredSynchronization.beforeCompletion(RegisteredSynchronization.java:37)
        at org.wildfly.transaction.client@1.1.13.Final//org.wildfly.transaction.client.AbstractTransaction.performConsumer(AbstractTransaction.java:236)
        at org.wildfly.transaction.client@1.1.13.Final//org.wildfly.transaction.client.AbstractTransaction.performConsumer(AbstractTransaction.java:247)
        at org.wildfly.transaction.client@1.1.13.Final//org.wildfly.transaction.client.AbstractTransaction$AssociatingSynchronization.beforeCompletion(AbstractTransaction.java:292)
        at org.jboss.jts//com.arjuna.ats.internal.jta.resources.arjunacore.SynchronizationImple.beforeCompletion(SynchronizationImple.java:76)
        at org.jboss.jts//com.arjuna.ats.arjuna.coordinator.TwoPhaseCoordinator.beforeCompletion(TwoPhaseCoordinator.java:360)
        at org.jboss.jts//com.arjuna.ats.arjuna.coordinator.TwoPhaseCoordinator.end(TwoPhaseCoordinator.java:91)
        at org.jboss.jts//com.arjuna.ats.arjuna.AtomicAction.commit(AtomicAction.java:162)
        at org.jboss.jts//com.arjuna.ats.internal.jta.transaction.arjunacore.TransactionImple.commitAndDisassociate(TransactionImple.java:1295)
        at org.jboss.jts//com.arjuna.ats.internal.jta.transaction.arjunacore.BaseTransaction.commit(BaseTransaction.java:126)
        at org.jboss.jts.integration//com.arjuna.ats.jbossatx.BaseTransactionManagerDelegate.commit(BaseTransactionManagerDelegate.java:94)
        at org.wildfly.transaction.client@1.1.13.Final//org.wildfly.transaction.client.LocalTransaction.commitAndDissociate(LocalTransaction.java:78)      
        at org.wildfly.transaction.client@1.1.13.Final//org.wildfly.transaction.client.ContextTransactionManager.commit(ContextTransactionManager.java:71) 
        at org.keycloak.keycloak-services@14.0.0//org.keycloak.transaction.JtaTransactionWrapper.commit(JtaTransactionWrapper.java:90)
        ... 50 more
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: value too long for type character varying(255)
        at org.postgresql.jdbc@42.2.5//org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.receiveErrorResponse(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2440)
        at org.postgresql.jdbc@42.2.5//org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.processResults(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2183)
        at org.postgresql.jdbc@42.2.5//org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.execute(QueryExecutorImpl.java:308)
        at org.postgresql.jdbc@42.2.5//org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.executeInternal(PgStatement.java:441)
        at org.postgresql.jdbc@42.2.5//org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.execute(PgStatement.java:365)
        at org.postgresql.jdbc@42.2.5//org.postgresql.jdbc.PgPreparedStatement.executeWithFlags(PgPreparedStatement.java:143)
        at org.postgresql.jdbc@42.2.5//org.postgresql.jdbc.PgPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PgPreparedStatement.java:120)
        at org.jboss.ironjacamar.jdbcadapters@1.4.27.Final//org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.WrappedPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(WrappedPreparedStatement.java:537)
        at org.hibernate@5.3.20.Final//org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.executeUpdate(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:175)
        ... 78 more
```

Comment: You have better error (backtrace) in keycloak logs.

Comment: @JanGaraj the keycloak error logs are in below link:

https://gist.github.com/kurianbenoy-aot/5c77cf8f30185501d0c930fdb68ee46f

Comment: Always provides logs in the question, not on the external site.

Answer (score 1):

See your error backtrace:

```
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: 
ERROR: value too long for type character varying(255)
```

So DB field where that payload should be saved has max size 255 characters, but your payload exceeds this size. It makes sense, because those attributes are not designated to save anything. They have limits - it this case it is determined by used DB column type - max 255 characters.

Comment: you have pointed at the the issue correctly. Is there anyway I can increase the DB column type size?